# How do I make my AndroidManifest.xml editable again?

Tags: android-studio-3.0

I'm developing my first apps in Android Studio (3.1.2) and I've managed to complicate my life by making my AndroidManifest.xml file read-only in one of my projects. When I click on it in the Project view, it comes up as two panes side by side, neither of which is the view I'm used to from my other projects; the view on the right says "Merging Log Value provided by Gradle"; the view on the left only allows me to DELETE lines of the manifest but I want to add some lines. I assume these views are useful to *someone* but they aren't to me at the moment. I'm just trying to do a straight-forward edit on the file and I can't find any option to make it appear in the editable way that I'm used to from other projects. I think I must have clicked on something somewhere in the Android Studio GUI that caused this problem but I'm darned if I know what I did.

If someone could tell me how to make the file editable again, I'd be grateful for your guidance. Bonus points if you tell me how I messed myself up so that I can avoid doing it in the future!

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this was very easily solved. I just noticed that there are TWO tabs available when you look at a manifest.xml and I was in the "merged manifest" tab. As soon as I clicked on the "text" tab, my manifest.xml file appeared in its normal fully-editable form.

I must have clicked on Merged Manifest - although I don't remember doing so! - and then simply not seen the tab again until just now.

My insomnia's been pretty bad this week so I'm going to chalk this up to that. :-)

Anyway, I'm just going to leave this question and answer here in case it helps someone else some time in the future.

Comment: I thought I broke the entire IDE because of this. Thanks for pointing this out. In fact it is a neat feature!